# ASUS G75VW WinFlash Utility BIOS will not let me boot up my drives

Tags: windows-7, bios, asus-laptop

Not sure exactly what I did wrong, but I had just installed Windows 7 on my computer, and was about to update the BIOS of my ASUS G75VW laptop using the Win-flash Utility program on their support website. After doing this, my computer restarted and booted into the BIOS(Now I believe it's completely written over all of my files and drive) and it only allows me to change the settings from the BIOS, and delete Boot Options(Which it shows none). I'm completely baffled on how I can get my things back, if only to try and install Windows 7(along with all the drivers for ASUS) again.

Comment: Why were you trying to flash the BIOS anyway? It's *never* a good idea to do this if you don't know what you're doing. Have you tried booting from the Win7 DVD yet?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought I should havve done i, but apparently I was wrong. I have, but it's not letting me boot from anything. It shows the option for deleting Boot Options, but not adding any.

Comment: "not letting me boot from anything." Does that include USB? If it allows USB but not HDD or CD, check if the SATA AHCI controller is enabled. If that is not it, try a 'reset to defaults' in the BIOS.

Comment: I tried reset to defaults i few times, but its not showing boot options for anything.

Comment: Go over all the BIOS settings, every setting on every page, and make sure it's correct. Pay particular attention to SATA controller settings such as AHCI/RAID modes.

Comment: The SATA mode is set to AHCI

Comment: Is it supposed to be set to AHCI though? Was it set to AHCI before?

Comment: Yes it was i believe.